# How do you set up Vue 3 main.js file with extra imports?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, aws-amplify, vuejs3, aws-amplify-vue

Hi I'm trying to do the vue 3 version of main.js file that works in vue 2

vue 2

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import store from "./store";
import Amplify, * as AmplifyModules from "aws-amplify";
import { AmplifyPlugin } from "aws-amplify-vue";
import awsmobile from "./aws-exports";

Amplify.configure(awsmobile);
Vue.use(AmplifyPlugin, AmplifyModules);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
new Vue({
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

vue 3 best guess

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue'

import Amplify, * as AmplifyModules from 'aws-amplify'
import { AmplifyPlugin } from 'aws-amplify-vue'
import awsconfig from './aws-exports'

const app = createApp(App)

Amplify.configure(awsconfig)

app.use(AmplifyPlugin, AmplifyModules)

app.mount('#app')
```

Works without extra imports then just shows a white screen when I add them

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason is that the plugin structure changed in vue3

I suspect if you comment out this line: `app.use(AmplifyPlugin, AmplifyModules)` it'll work (without the plugin)

Doesn't look like the plugin shares a repo, so it's hard to get into the workings of it.

There's an article that talks about the differences a bit here (look for provide/inject)

https://medium.com/better-programming/designing-vue3-plugins-using-provide-and-inject-47b586d9ce4

You may have to roll your own plugin for vue3, or continue to use vue2.